# Can AuthnProviderAlias ldap work with Apache2.4.x?

Tags: c, apache, configuration, ldap

This works perfectly in Apache2.2, but not in 2.4 (and I *need* to use 2.4 now):

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap myldap>
  AuthLDAPBindDN cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
  AuthLDAPBindPassword xxxx
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://localhost:9011/dc=example,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)
</AuthnProviderAlias>

Listen 48443
<VirtualHost myserver:48443>
 <Directory /path/to/a/folder>
        Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all

        AuthBasicProvider myldap mySecondLdap myThirdLdap ...

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "LDAP authentication for folder"
        Require valid-user
        ...
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Using directly the directives from [Apache 2.4 mod_authnz_ldap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html) works in the `<Directory >` section:

```
AuthLDAPBindDN cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
AuthLDAPBindPassword xxx
AuthLDAPURL ldap://localhost:9011/dc=example,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)
AuthBasicProvider ldap
```

But that allows an authentication **against only *one* LDAP server**, and I have to authenticate against at least two.
Hence the use of [`AuthnProviderAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authnprovideralias), which is now (2.4) part of [`mod_authn_core` core authentication module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_core.html), instead of the old [2.2 LDAP authentication module `mod_authn_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_alias.html).

---

I have compiled all 2.4.x versions (from 2.4.1 to 2.4.6, and even current), with [APR 1.4.8, and APR-util 1.5.2](http://apr.apache.org/), in debug mode (`-g -O0`)

What I tried is a debug session ( `gdb --command=debug`, with '`debug`' a gdb parameter file as follow):

```
file /home/vonc/usr/local/apps/apache/bin/httpd
set logging file /home/vonc/gdb.txt
set logging on
set args -X
show args
set breakpoint pending on

# authn_alias_check_password
b mod_authn_core.c:115
# authaliassection
b mod_authn_core.c:203
b mod_authn_core.c:255

run
wh
fs next
where
```

What I see is:

- the [`authaliassection` function of `mod_authn_core`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blame/trunk/modules/aaa/mod_authn_core.c#L194-L207) is called *twice*, probably because of [`server/main.c`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/server/main.c) calls `ap_process_config_tree` *twice* ([once here](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blame/trunk/server/main.c#L639), and [once there](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blame/trunk/server/main.c#L739-L742)) in the same [`main()` function](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/server/main.c#L438).

That function [gets the `authcfg`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/aaa/mod_authn_core.c#L204-L206)

```
authn_alias_srv_conf *authcfg =
    (authn_alias_srv_conf *)ap_get_module_config(r->server->module_config,
                                                 &authn_core_module);
```

And [sets the provider](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/aaa/mod_authn_core.c#L267-L273) with the right name '`ldap`' and right alias '`myldap`'

```
apr_hash_set(authcfg->alias_rec, provider_alias, APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, prvdraliasrec);
```

BUT: when the password needs to be checked (in [`authn_alias_check_password`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/aaa/mod_authn_core.c#L107-L108), it gets `authcfg` again, and [fetch the provider](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/aaa/mod_authn_core.c#L122-L123):

```
    provider_alias_rec *prvdraliasrec = apr_hash_get(authcfg->alias_rec,
                                                     provider_name, APR_HASH_KEY_STRING);
```

It uses the right `provider_name` '`myldap`', ... and that always returns `null`.
that means [`prvdraliasrec->provider->check_password`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/aaa/mod_authn_core.c#L128-L131) never get called.

A similar question in the [http-dev mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/) ([August 23, 2013 "Is AuthnProviderAlias subtly broken in 2.4?"](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/201308.mbox/%3C5215672C.8090304@aldan.algebra.com%3E)) was... unanswered.

How would you troubleshoot this bug?

Comment: My only suggestion would be to use gdb to track the authentication sequence for a server with a working ldap configuration, hopefully this will expose the divergence between the behaviour of the configurations

Comment: @GearoidMurphy that would mean tracking in a Apache 2.2. And there was some massive refactoring between 2.2 and 2.4... Not easy to pinpoint an error in code that was moved around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug is due to the providers and their usage being in different server contexts.

- mod_authn_core provides AuthType, which causes a per-server config to be created for authn_core in for the VH
- The module implements no merge function
- server->module_config which will always be empty.

Workaround: Define your auth outside of VH context, or try this patch if you can rebuild easily: http://people.apache.org/~covener/patches/authprovider.diff

```
Index: modules/aaa/mod_authn_core.c
===================================================================
--- modules/aaa/mod_authn_core.c    (revision 40703)
+++ modules/aaa/mod_authn_core.c    (working copy)
@@ -179,6 +179,12 @@
     return (void *) authcfg;
 }

+/* Only per-server directive we have is GLOBAL_ONLY */
+static void *merge_authn_alias_svr_config(apr_pool_t *p, void *basev, void *overridesv)
+{
+    return basev;
+}
+
 static const authn_provider authn_alias_provider =
 {
     &authn_alias_check_password,
@@ -373,7 +379,7 @@
     create_authn_core_dir_config,   /* dir config creater */
     merge_authn_core_dir_config,    /* dir merger --- default is to override */
     create_authn_alias_svr_config,  /* server config */
-    NULL,                           /* merge server config */
+    merge_authn_alias_svr_config,   /* merge server config */
     authn_cmds,
     register_hooks                  /* register hooks */
 };
```

Comment: 2.2 works because AuthType and <authnprovideralias> were not in the same module

Comment: +1 in advance. I will test that next Monday at work. I can rebuild any version I want and apply any patch. That is what I have been doing for the past few months with my `pre` (`pre-make`) step: https://raw.github.com/VonC/compileEverything/master/.cpl/params/apache

Comment: Yes!!! Finally. It seems to work just fine with Apache 2.4.7 recompiled with the patch in it. I wonder if that patch will make it in 2.4.8 or 2.5.

Comment: Has anyone filed a bug for this with the Apache project?

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution I found is to patch [`mod_authn_core.c`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/aaa/mod_authn_core.c), adding 2 global variables, one for each LDAP alias I want to work with.

That seems ugly: the two LDAP alias names are hardcoded in the code.

See [commit 2f691a6](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/commit/2f691a690016e490402d0cea90cc01ed69058c94)

```
provider_alias_rec *prvdraliasrec_myldap;
provider_alias_rec *prvdraliasrec_companyldap;
```

That way, [`merge_authn_core_dir_config()`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/f0fef42d535e55a790088d4dc3de79a6cf061cd2/modules/aaa/mod_authn_core.c#L82) looks for those two alias names specifically to register them.

```
if (!prvdraliasrec && strcmp(provider_name,"myldap")==0) {
  prvdraliasrec=prvdraliasrec_myldap; 
}
if (!prvdraliasrec && strcmp(provider_name,"companyldap")==0) {
  prvdraliasrec=prvdraliasrec_companyldap;
}
```

And [`authaliassection()`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/f0fef42d535e55a790088d4dc3de79a6cf061cd2/modules/aaa/mod_authn_core.c#L194) get those alias definition back

```
if ( strcmp(provider_alias,"myldap") == 0 ) { 
  prvdraliasrec_myldap = prvdraliasrec;
}
if ( strcmp(provider_alias,"companyldap") == 0 ) {
  prvdraliasrec_companyldap = prvdraliasrec;
}
```

It works, but it certainly isn't the "right" solution.

Comment: if you're still familiar with this code, I'm curious if you could look at my answer here: https://serverfault.com/a/1109472/27515

Comment: @larsks I am no longer familiar with this code, but I did enthusiastically upvoted your answer. I just hope you all are using a more recent version than Apache 2.2 or early 2.4. Darned, the stable version is *still* 2.4.xx in 2022!?

Comment: thanks for taking a look! I'm using the official docker image, which gets me 2.4.54 (released 08-June-2022).